# jQuery ColorBox as POP UP. No Show Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, colorbox

I am Using Colorbox for a Pop-Up that loads when the page loads. The Pop Up Calls an ASP page with 1 Image, and 1 Button that launches a Chat Window.

I got it to work on my local, but when I go remote the images dont appear (all the file paths are correct it looks like). The functionality is there and you can click on the invisible chat button, but no Images. If you have a second anytime this week OR next, I need this to work for my work.
>

> The Page I am working on is: www.702wedding.com/linkto.asp
>   The Page it Calls is : www.702wedding.com/chat-with-us.asp

Also, can it be set on a 5 second Timer?
Thanks People!

Answer (score 1):

You need to upload the image files to the webserver.

If you navigate to `http://www.702wedding.com/images/chat-invites/chat-image-staff.png`, you'll get a 404 Not Found error.

Comment: Thank Man, I have uploaded the images before, I think another web dev overwrote them.